# Access Function within ChildActorClass of UChildActorComponent

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Okay, so on UE4 I'm attempting to make a UChildActorComponent that serves as the player's weapon. But when I go to call a function within the APlayerWeapon class, it says:

> error: no member named 'Shoot' in 'UChildActorComponent'

Here's the code I use to initialize the weapon:

```
void ABaseCharacter::CreatePlayerWeapon()
{
    //Create the weapon actor as a UChildActorComponent
    Weapon = CreateDefaultSubobject<UChildActorComponent>(TEXT("PlayerWeapon"));
    Weapon->SetChildActorClass(WeaponClass);
    Weapon->CreateChildActor();

    //Attach it at the socket called "GunSocket" that I created on the right hand
    Weapon->SetupAttachment(GetMesh(), FName("GunSocket"));
}
```

Then in the SetupPlayerInputComponent function, I use this to try and bind "Shoot()" to the spacebar key (which is set as the input in game settings):

```
InputComponent->BindAction("Shoot", IE_Pressed, this, Weapon->Shoot());
```

And here are the relevant lines of code from the ABaseCharacter header file:

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly)
    class UChildActorComponent* Weapon;


UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Base Character")
    TSubclassOf<class APlayerWeapon> WeaponClass;
```

And then the relevant lines of code from the APlayerWeapon class:

```
void APlayerWeapon::Shoot()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Shooting"));
}
```

tldr; How can I access the Shoot() function from APlayerWeapon if the weapon is currently a ChildActorComponent?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to solve this issue. You just need to get the child actor, then cast to the child actor class. Then you're able to call the function.

```
((APlayerWeapon *)Weapon->GetChildActor())->Shoot();
```